# Clicking Create Custom or Explore Processor Fails

Tags: cloud-document-ai

When I click on either of the explore or create processors in doc ai, it fails.  I’ve tried different browsers, machines, etc., to no avail.

When I click on either of the explore or create processors in doc ai, it fails.  I’ve tried different browsers, machines, etc., to no avail.  I tried different networks as well in case of firewall errors.

It says ‘failed to load’ every time.

Comment: Could you provide more information? Has this always occurred for you? Is this the first time you're trying to use Document AI or Google Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the DocumentAI APIs. The interface and errors do not indicate this, but if you follow the tutorial on the right side, you will see a button that allows you to do just that.

[image]

If you start this tutorial, there is a button on the first page if your APIs aren't enabled. You will need sufficient access to your project to be able to enable the API.

[image]